# Cannot read property 'date' of undefined - only when FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have a weird problem.
the process:

**1)** i fetch from api in useEffect an array of object of `meetings`

```
useEffect(() => {
        trackPromise(
            bookingContext.getUserMeetings(state.token, state.userId),
            "getUserMeetings"
        );
}, []);
```

**2)** i render the array conditinally if his render (so first render is empty - and after useEffect is get the array from the "MeetingContext"

```
{bookingContext.state.userMeetings.length > 0 ? (
   <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{bookingContext.state.userMeetings[0].date}</Text>.............
```

**So far it works**

now when i change the last row `( bookingContext.state.userMeetings[0].date} )`
to flat list like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={bookingContext.state.userMeetings}
    renderItem={({ meet }) => (
        <Text>{meet.date}</Text>
    )}
    keyExtractor={meet => meet._id}
/>
```

and try to render he tell me **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined"**
he does not care my conditionnaly or nothing.. its just crush.

**4)** **i use in react-promise-tracker for the loading and wrap the use effect with it.

**the question :** why with flat list it doesnt work and in regular syntax(like part 2) it works.

**question 2:** there is a way to tell react to first wait until the promise done in the use effect and just after he finish to render the array?

Comment: According to the FlatList List docs you are using wrong property which doesn't exist in FlatList renderItem API for rendering data.
Instead of { meet } you have to user { item  } as item property has your Array data. Meet property doesn't exist in FlatList.

Comment: Oops ! I thought that "item" its just name that i can choose  like the map method meetings.map(meet/item/whatever i want"=> . So now i understand tgat is must be "item" on the flatlist. Yeah?  And thanxfrom advabce

Comment: Please upvote my comment and close this issue